# rangevalidator c# how to use later in code

Tags: c#, rangevalidator

I created a range validator and would like to trigger it once the submit button was clicked.

```
RangeValidator rv_tbAbsenceDay = new RangeValidator();
rv_tbAbsenceDay.ID = "rv_tbAbsenceDay" + tbAbsenceDay.ID;
rv_tbAbsenceDay.ControlToValidate = tbAbsenceDay.ID;
rv_tbAbsenceDay.EnableClientScript = true;
rv_tbAbsenceDay.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic;
rv_tbAbsenceDay.MinimumValue = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6).ToString("d");
rv_tbAbsenceDay.MaximumValue = DateTime.Now.ToString("d");
rv_tbAbsenceDay.ErrorMessage = "Date cannot be older than 6 months and not in the future.";
rv_tbAbsenceDay.SetFocusOnError = true;
plcMyStaff.Controls.Add(rv_tbAbsenceDay);
```

plcMyStaff is a placeholder.

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="plcMyStaff" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

How do I get hold of the created range validator to trigger it i.e. `rv.validate();` ?

I have tried this:

```
protected void MarkAsSick_Command(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList tempddlReason = (DropDownList)plcMyStaff.FindControl("ddlReason" + e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    TextBox temptbAbsenceDay = (TextBox)plcMyStaff.FindControl("tbAbsenceDay" + e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    TextBox temptbLastDayWorked = (TextBox)plcMyStaff.FindControl("tbLastDayWorked" + e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    RangeValidator temprv_tbAbsenceDay = (RangeValidator)plcMyStaff.FindControl("rv_tbAbsenceDay" + e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    temprv_tbAbsenceDay.validate();
...
```

Hope you can help me.

thanks,

Andy

Comment: Where have you declared your instance of the Validator? Is all that code in the same class?

Comment: What is happening when you execute the MarkAsSick_Command? Have you checked to see if it finds the control? I.E does temprv_tvAsenceDay have an instance of an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off to debug this I would suggest examining the `plcMyStaff` object in which you are adding the control to see if it does in fact contain the control you wish to access.

You should be able to retrieve it from the `Page` object that your webform inherits.

```
Page.FindControl();

// Or you can Iterate through each control to see what the control is called and test for the name you want
foreach (var control in Page.Controls)
{

}
```